# Is there any feature for Universal Windows App to support multiple flavor (in Android) or target (in iOS)?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows

Right now it's possible to build multiple flavors ( not version ) of Android app or iOS app using "flavor" and "target" features respectively. Already have created iOS and Android apps which need such "flavoring". Now same app is to be developed as Windows Universal App. Is it possible to do it in current SDK of Universal Windows App?

Answer (score 1):

Universal Windows Apps are apps that run on windows 10. At the moment there is only one "flavor" of windows 10 so you can only build against that. As more updates come you will be able to target any range of versions and device families you like.

[It's all mentioned in this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894631.aspx#device_families).

**EDIT: Different meaning of flavors**

If by flavors you mean keeping the same code base with minor changes and publishing multiple flavors of an app then I am not aware of any tool that provides such capability in visual studio.

if that is what you want then you will have to do it manually. Create the store packages for the first flavor of your app, then perform the code base changes (by adding or removing files or an other way you want) and then create the new store packages.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Corcus, but I'm not referring to windows 10 or any other operating system or device by "flavor". "Flavor" in the sense, same app but different branding. Android use flavor terminology for such different branding.

Comment: @HBB20 It's nothing :)

Comment: I looked into other forums, but none of them helped.

Comment: @HBB20 I see what you mean now. You want to have the same app with minor changes in it's code and those changes constitute the flavors. Right?

I am not aware of a tool that provides such features in visual studio :(. I'll edit my answer to reflect that